# How to replace two class attribute in html content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my project, I fetch html content from DB with ajax, and these content will appear in web in div with id of timeTagDiv.

If My name is John, it should appears:

```
                                                17:05:31 John translatetomaintanceGroup
                                                                         letMnGrpmakeit

 17:05:53 snow acceptSheet
 17:06:04 snow translatetoleadGrp
 leadercheckit
```

If my name is snow, it should appears:

```
17:05:31 John translatetomaintanceGroup
letMnGrpmakeit     

                                                             17:05:53 snow acceptSheet
                                                      17:06:04 snow translatetoleadGrp
                                                                         leadercheckit
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
var stChr="John";
var stTrnStr="translateto";
$.ajax({
        ......
        success:function(data) 
        { 
         var $myHtml = $(data.stPrc);
         $myHtml.find("label").filter(function(){
             return $(this).text()===stChr;
             }).parent().attr("class", "rightd");
         //$myHtml.find('div:contains('+stChr+' '+stTrnStr+')').next().attr('class','rightd');
         $('#timeTagDiv').html($myHtml);
        }
    });
```

Here is the content of data.stPrc from DB:

```
<div class="leftd">
 <label>17:05:31</label>&nbsp;
 <label>John</label>
 <label>&nbsp;translateto</label>
 <label>maintanceGroup</label>
</div>
<div class="leftd">
  <div class="speech left" >letMnGrpmakeit</div>
</div>
<div class="leftd"><label>17:05:53</label>&nbsp;
  <label>snow</label>
  <label>&nbsp;acceptSheet</label>
</div>
 <div class="leftd">
 <label>17:06:04</label>&nbsp;
 <label>snow</label>
 <label>&nbsp;translateto</label>
 <label>leadGrp</label>
</div>
<div class="leftd">
 <div class="speech left" >leadercheckit</div>
</div>
```

When the context of label is John, the attribute class of parent div changed to rightd. Here is the code working successfully:

```
$myHtml.find("label").filter(function(){
             return $(this).text()===stChr;
             }).parent().attr("class", "rightd");
```

And then,  the content of  letMnGrpmakeit belongs to John should at the right side. So the next two divs class should be set class="rightd" and class="speech right".

In my example, before:

```
<div class="leftd">
  <div class="speech left" >letMnGrpmakeit</div>
</div>
```

after replace:

```
<div class="rightd">
  <div class="speech right" >letMnGrpmakeit</div>
</div>
```

I use :

```
$myHtml.find('div:contains('+stChr+' '+stTrnStr+')').next().attr('class','rightd');
$myHtml.find('div:contains('+stChr+' '+stTrnStr+')').next().next().attr('class','speech right');
```

But unfortunately, they both worked fail.

I have tried one condition:

```
$myHtml.find('label:contains('+stTrnStr+')').parent().next().attr('class','rightd');
```

It works, but it appears like:

```
                                                17:05:31 John translatetomaintanceGroup
                                                                         letMnGrpmakeit

 17:05:53 snow acceptSheet
 17:06:04 snow translatetoleadGrp
                                                                            leadercheckit
```

"leadercheckit" should under "17:06:04 snow translatetoleadGrp", because it belongs to snow.

I have no idea about this. The key to change two div class are two conditions.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand everything correctly because of wording and grammar, but I would suggest using [addClass('className')](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass('className')](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) instead. This way if your element has more than one class, it will only remove the desired class. By using `.attr('class', 'className')`, you're replacing everything. If you wish to add multiple classes, just use `.addClass('class-1 class-2')`

Answer (score 0):

Use these:

```
$myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stTrnStr+')').parent().next().attr('class','rightd');

$myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stTrnStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right');
```